# Microsoft Office Interop Word Application stops working when memory consumption reaches around 63000K

Tags: .net, office-interop

I am using Microsoft Office Interop to generate some Word and PDF documents. After having sent certain number of requests for document generation, the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application` stops working/responding.

From looking at the task manager, I know that this happens when the `winword.exe` process has consumed around 63000K of memory [Please look in the snapshot]. I notice that with every request of document generation, the memory consumption increase by about 400-800K and when it reaches around 63000K, it stops working. **When the first request is received the `winword.exe` starts at memory consumption of around 20000K.**

[image: Memory consumption of WINWORD.EXE process]

This is the code that is used for document generation:

```
object templateName = "d:\\xyz.dotm";
object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
wordDocument = this.WordApplication.Documents.Add(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
wordDocument.Range(ref missing, ref missing).Text = "";
wordDocument.set_AttachedTemplate(ref templateName);

wordDocument = this.WordApplication.Documents.Open(
ref objSourceFilePath, ref oFalse, ref oTrue,
ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
ref oMissing);

 wordDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat(
strTargetPath,
targetFormat,
paramOpenAfterExport,
paramExportOptimizeFor,
paramExportRange,
paramStartPage,
paramEndPage,
paramExportItem,
paramIncludeDocProps,
paramKeepIRM,
paramCreateBookmarks,
paramDocStructureTags,
paramBitmapMissingFonts,
paramUseISO19005_1,
ref oMissing);

finally
{
    if (wordDocument != null)
    {
        wordDocument.Close(ref oFalse, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(wordDocument);
        wordDocument = null;
    }
}
```

I don't dispose off the `WordApplication` class or release it, because it is being saved inside an ApplicationPool and is used for further request processing.

Can anyone provide any help/pointers as to why the memory consumption keeps on increasing and then it stops responding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As no one has replied. I tried a workaround, when the WINWORD.EXE has generated about 30 documents, I quit the Word Application. There is no other option with me.

So, closing this question.

Answer (score 0):

Try closing the document in the application before releasing it; something like WordApplication.Documents.Close(...) if I recall correctly?

Comment: Isn't this line closing the document? - wordDocument.Close(ref oFalse, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

Comment: Right, it should, I was just thinking maybe it's not removed from the Documents collection somehow and it's causing some orphaned resources. I should probably delete the answer before I get downvoted into oblivion :P

Comment: Here's a thought, make the application visible and check if the documents are actually getting closed. Perhaps it's not such a good way to check but hey... Can't think of any other reason why memory would not be released.

Comment: Also, when I needed to generate things from a template, I'm pretty sure I used a different way, AttachedTemplate doesn't ring a bell, perhaps that's another possible cause. I'll try to find the way I did it and let you know.

Comment: I won't get home for a few more hours, I think I got the code somewhere there; however I think I just opened the .dotm as a document, then saved it to somewhere else. Ah, but I see you're probably doing something else entirely here, not generating documents from a template...

Answer (score 0):

```
public void DisposeExcelInstance()
{
    app.DisplayAlerts = false;
    workBook.Close(null, null, null);
    app.Workbooks.Close();
    app.Quit();
    if (workSheet != null)
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workSheet);
    if (workBook != null)
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workBook);
    if (app != null)
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);
    workSheet = null;
    workBook = null;
    app = null;
    GC.Collect(); // force final cleanup!
}
```